# Populate dropdowns by ID from json

Tags: json

I have a JSON file. Originally it looked like this:

```
{"marki": [
        { "name": "Access", "models": [ "Max", "Acce" ] },
        { "name": "Adly", "models": [ "Adly1", "Adly2" ] }]
}
```

Unfortunately, this is a bad thing because the model names are repeated. So I added an ID for each model. The ID I have from the Wordpress database.
I made a JSON like this:

```
{"marki": [
            { "name": "Access",  "models": [ { "name":"Max", "id": 6206}, { "name":"Acce", "id": 6207} ] },
            { "name": "Adly", "models": [ { "name":"Adly1", "id": 6208}, { "name":"Adly2", "id": 6209} ] }]
}
```

For that I have a JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var marki = {};
    var json = $.getJSON( wpp.uploads_dir + '/motocykle-marki.json');
    json.done(function(data){
        $.each(data.marki, function (index, marka){
            marki[marka.name] = marka.models;
        });
        console.log(marki);
    });
    $(document).on( 'change', '[data-wpt-field-title~="motocykle-marka"]', function(){
        var selected_model = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        $('[data-wpt-field-title~="motocykle-model"] > option').each(function(){
            if( $.inArray( $(this).text(), marki[selected_model]) == -1 ){
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This JS was written to the original JSON version, and now I do not know how to convert it to a new version. Now the second dropdown shows nothing.

**Edition -------------------------------------------------**

Here's a solution to the problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var marki = {};
    var json = $.getJSON( wpp.uploads_dir + '/motocykle-marki.json');

    json.done(function(data){
        $.each(data.marki, function (index, marka){
            marki[marka.name] = marka.models;
        });
        console.log(marki);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '[data-wpt-field-title~="motocykle-marka"]', function () {
     $('[data-wpt-field-title~="motocykle-model"] > option').hide();

     var selected_model = $(this).find(":selected").text();
     var models = marki[selected_model];
     for (var i in models) {
      var model = models[i];

      $('[data-wpt-field-title~="motocykle-model"] > option[value="' + model.id + '"]').show();
     }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
if( $.inArray( $(this).text(), marki[selected_model]) == -1 ){
```

with:

```
if( $.inArray( $(this).text(), marki[selected_model].map(function(a){return a.name;})) == -1 ){
```

Comment: It is better because the second select now shows models. But it still shows all models with similar names even if they do not belong to this brand. As in the beginning.